# Windsor don't resolve class constructor dependency

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have code (simplified)

Configuration:

```
_container.AddComponent<IRepository<Project>, FakeProjectRepository>();
var instance = new List<Project>();
_container.Kernel.AddComponentInstance<IList<Project>>(instance);
```

Class:

```
class FakeProjectRepository: IRepository<Project>
public FakeProjectRepository(IList<Project> entities)
    {
        _entities = entities.ToList();
    }
```

While resolving container.Resolve(repositoryType) throws

```
Can't create component 'Domain.Concrete.FakeRepositories.FakeProjectRepository' 
as it  has dependencies to be satisfied. 

Domain.Concrete.FakeRepositories.FakeProjectRepository
is waiting for the following dependencies: 

Keys (components with specific keys)
- entities which was not registered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are usually not treated as stand-alone services, but as service overrides or parameters. See the [Windsor FAQ](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.FAQ.ashx#Why_is_Windsor_not_able_to_inject_array_or_list_of_components_7) and the [Windsor documentation on Resolvers](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx#Standard_resolvers_9).